# git: hide detailed commit on branch

Tags: git

I'm wondering if this is possible in git. So I have the master branch. Now and again I'll create a side branch for a feature development. When that's finished, I'll merge it back to master. Now normally all the commit history on the side branch will be shown in the master branch. Is there a way to make all the commit to appear as one on the master?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The commit history is important. If it isn't, just develop your entire feature in a single patch (or squash your series to a single patch when you're done).

Comment: Are you using a Git plugin here, or just the command line?

Comment: You can squash the commits, but you'll still gonna have one left. More here: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

Comment: @Mureinik it feels cleaner and if I remember correctly, clearcase does this.

Comment: If I understand well, you want it to be as if the side branch never existed, and all commits made on that side branch are on the master branch?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen command line

Comment: It would have helped if you posted a sample merge commit comment, along with what you don't like about it.

Comment: @lang2 any news on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash <branch>
```

From the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) (**emphasis** mine):

> **--squash**
>   --no-squash
>   Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually
>   make a commit, move the HEAD, or record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD (to cause
>   the next git commit command to create a merge commit). **This allows you
>   to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is
>   the same as merging another branch** (or more in case of an octopus).
>
> With --no-squash perform the merge and commit the result. This option
>   can be used to override --squash.

Comment: in case he wants to put all his commits into one single commit, this is indeed a faster solution. If not, my answer allows that.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you made your developments on a **side branch**:

```
git checkout -b dev_branch
< do your changes, and commit them >
```

Now if you want all commits to appear as **one single commit**, you do the following. If you want to keep all commits as they are, skip to the following step.

```
git rebase -i master
< in the interface you should now keep the first commit, and select `squash` for all the successive commits >
```

now you want to **rebase** your master branch on your **side branch** and delete that branch:

```
git checkout master
git rebase dev_branch
git branch -d dev_branch
```

Comment: I love `git rebase` but I don't know if this is what the OP wants.  I thought that merging would leave only _one_ commit and therefore _one_ comment, but maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: `git rebase` ftw :). indeed, git merge adds one commit. But the OP says he wants to make "all the commit to appear as one on the master"

Comment: The outcome of `git merge --squash` is exactly the same while running a single command. Besides, you keep the `dev_branch`'s original history.

Comment: you are right, the output is the same as all the commands proposed by me, except the last one (deleting the branch). My solution allows him to keep the multiple commits from `dev_branch` if he wishes.